# Trying to create a heatmap of Home Wins/Away Wins/Draws

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, heatmap, pandas-styles

Using the [Kaggle EPL](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/irkaal/english-premier-league-results) dataset and `epl=df.dropna().reset_index(drop=True)`.
I'm trying to create a heatmap similar to this:

[image: Season 2000-01]
The columns needed to create the heatmap from the dataset would be as follows:

| Season | HomeTeam | AwayTeam | FTHG(Fulltime HomeGoal) | FTAG(Fulltime AwayGoal) | FTR(Fulltime Result) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

The given reference image is of 2000-01 season so I hope to swap the season to retrieve it's corresponding heatmap.

Also the abbreviated names on top is not necessary, I can have the x-axis name label on the bottom and rotated 90deg.

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried already that isn't working?

Comment: To create a heatmap for 2000-01 Season. I'm fairly new to Python and Pandas and learning so I'm not sure how to go about creating the syntax for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proposition with [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) pivoting & [*Styler*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.html) :

```
df = pd.read_csv("results.csv", encoding="latin-1",
                 usecols=["Season", "HomeTeam", "AwayTeam", "FTHG", "FTAG", "FTR"])

df["FinalScore"] = df["FTHG"].astype(str).str.cat(df["FTAG"].astype(str), sep="-")
df = df[df["Season"].eq("2000-01")] #feel free to change the filter's value 
dfp_vals = (df.pivot(index="HomeTeam", columns="AwayTeam", values="FinalScore")
                .fillna("").rename_axis(index=None, columns="Home / Away"))
dfp_mask = df.pivot(index="HomeTeam", columns="AwayTeam", values="FTR").fillna("")

def heatmap(df):
    d_map = {
     "H": f"background-color: #bbf3ff;text-align: center;font-size: 12pt", #Home Win
     "D": f"background-color: #ffffbb;text-align: center;font-size: 12pt", #Draw
     "A": f"background-color: #ffbbbb;text-align: center;font-size: 12pt", #Away Win
     "":  f"background-color: #bbbbbb" # Diagonal (\)
    }
    return dfp_mask.replace(d_map)

def format_index(ser):
    return ["""background-color: #eaecf0; color: #3366cc;
            font-weight: lighter;font-size: 12pt""" for _ in ser]

def format_columns(ser):
    return ["background-color: #eaecf0; color: #3366cc" for _ in ser]

(
    dfp_vals.style.apply(heatmap, axis=None) # Excel friendly
        .apply_index(format_index, axis="index")
        .apply_index(format_columns, axis="columns")
        .format_index(lambda x: str.upper(x)[:3], axis="columns")
        .set_properties(**{"border":"1px solid gray"})
        .set_table_styles([{"selector": "td,th", "props": "line-height: 8px;"}])
)
```

Output :

[image]